# If .div.fixed:active then add border to main div (how to?)

Tags: javascript, css

LoL, the title has even confused me a little xD Apologies.

I have a fixed element div where once you scroll over it, it follows, simple no problem there.
Now, I'd like to add a simple border to the .div once the div.class is activated by javascript.

Here is an example : http://jsfiddle.net/2ds2y/

once .main.fixed is activated I'd like to add `border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;` to the .main div.
I've been reading around but I haven't been able to make this work, I tried the following.

```
.main.fixed:active ~ .main {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a border rule to your CSS fixed class:

```
.main.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2ds2y/3/)**

When the class is applied and the div is fixed, the border will be added.

Answer (score 0):

Ya friend simply add this line to the bottom of the CSS which is applied on .main.fixed

```
border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
```

like this

```
.main.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
}
```